# Populate second array in an object with values from its first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have situation like this

```
const links = {
  ALLOWED1: [ 'some_path1' ],
  ALLOWED2: [ 'some_path2' ]
}
```

However I want to also allow paths from previous array on `ALLOWED2`, I've tried

```
const links = {
  ALLOWED1: [ 'some_path1' ],
  ALLOWED2: [ ...links['ALLOWED1'], 'some_path2' ]
}
```

But this is not valid as `links` will not defined yet. Of course I can populate it manually, but would rather find a more elegant solution.

Comment: `ALLOWED2'` should be `ALLOWED2:`

Comment: @KevinKloet thank you, fixed :)

Comment: How do you populate the object?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Manually, this is for routing, however I would like to find a solution to get strings from previous array and move them into next one, that wouldn't be manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with three lines instead

```js
const links = {};
links.ALLOWED1 = [ 'some_path1' ];
links.ALLOWED2 = [ ...links['ALLOWED1'], 'some_path2' ];

console.log(links.ALLOWED2);
```

Remember, const only keeps the reference to the object constant, not the object's contents. For that you would need [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

If the contents of allowed1 and allowed2 ever change I might consider using a function to get them both. Like: `links.all = () => [...links.ALLOWED1, ...links.ALLOWED2]`. To me, that would read clearer in the code, unless it's really clear that allowed2 will always be a superset of allowed1.

Comment: Oops, thank you. Wish stackoverflow had a syntax checker :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to change `ALLOWED2`, you can convert it to a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const links = {
  ALLOWED1: [ 'some_path1' ],
  get ALLOWED2() { return [ ...this['ALLOWED1'], 'some_path2' ] }
}

console.log(links.ALLOWED2);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, just because there are many ways to do this and it's mostly a matter of style :)

```js
const links = (() => {
  const ALLOWED1 = ["some_path1"],
        ALLOWED2 = [...ALLOWED1, "some_path2"];
               
  return { ALLOWED1, ALLOWED2 };
})();

console.log(links);
```